# Nifi responds and than stops quickly and starts again. Need solution

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I have installed NIFI and when I run NIFI it starts well and shows the UI when accessed. I've made many flows. Different headers having different ports. Now what happens is, when I HIT using postman putting the specific header port such as localhost:10004/spec and gets it. Sometimes gets it, sometimes shows a 404 error and says no response but if clicked again to GET. It responds and then not. In short, nifi is constantly starting and stopping its services, but the nifi status shows that it's always running.

Latest logs:
[image]

Comment: Would be helpful to provide a template xml of your flow, the logs are showing errors related to ConvertJsonToAvro and are not showing anything about your ListenHttp processors

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Bryan. But I dont think the closing and opening of nifi time to time is because of this template.